# JQuery tablesorter with build-table-widget need to exclude last row from sorting

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the JQuery Tablesorter plugin, the fork from Mottie, and specifically the build-table widget. I'm needing the last row to be EXCLUDED when doing column sorting. The CSV file I'm using with the build-table widget contains in the last row the totals for the respective columns. So the last few lines of the CSV file is:

```
name, number1, number2, number3
,,, (blank row)
totals, sum, sum, sum
```

The problem is when I run the build-table widget it includes the last row when sorting. I have tried other plugin like the math widget, and the static-row widget. I've noticed I can get the static class added to the last row, BUT when I click a header to sort the static row is suddenly lost. All the examples I run across using these plugins are apart from using the build-table plugin. Another thing, the generated HTML that build-table creates DOES contain a `<tfoot></tfoot>` but it is empty. I have even tried to use something like JQuery `.wrap()` and manually wrap the last `tr` element of the `tbody` but it still is getting sorted :(  So, my question is, is there any way to get the build-table widget to exclude the last row from sorting when it builds the table? Or to put the last line of the CSV file in the generated `tfoot` tags? One thing I read in the build-table documentation options says "Any value contained within this option will override any footer text obtained from the CSV data." If this could be a solution, I am unsure of how to mark the CSV file with footer text.
Thanks you guys, my table is really close!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the build table widget with CSV data ([docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html#setup__csv_txt_within_dom_element)). There are `build_footers` options to make the last line a footer, apply class names and change the text ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/hnzph5us/7/)):

```
$(function() {
  $('#table').tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    widgets : ['zebra'],
    widgetOptions : {
      // *** build widget core ***
      build_type     : 'csv',
      build_source   : $('.csv'),
      // triggered event when build completes
      build_complete : 'tablesorter-build-complete',

      // *** CSV & array ***
      build_headers   : {
        rows    : 1,  // Number of header rows from the csv
        classes : [], // Header classes to apply to cells
        text    : [], // Header cell text
        widths  : ['27%', '50%', '20%'] // set header cell widths
      },
      build_footers : {
        rows    : 1,  // Number of header rows from the csv
        classes : [], // Footer classes to apply to cells
        text    : ['A', 'B', 'C'] // Footer cell text
      },

      // *** CSV options ***
      build_csvStartLine : 0,  // line within the csv to start adding to table
      build_csvSeparator : "," // csv separator
    }
  });
});
```

Change the `build_footers.text` to match the footer text you want (e.g. `[ "Total", "Sum", ... ]`)

Comment: Mottie, can I do something like build_footers and just give it the number of rows I want to be the footer? I can't hard code the footer titles because I'm getting the data from an external CSV file, so they may change. I just want the table builder to pick up the last row imported and put it as the footer. I'm experimenting with it now, but not getting it to work. The table is doing the headers perfectly without the build_headers array. Thank you for your help! - Tom

Comment: I think it has to be the way the table is being built from the external csv file. Its not pretty but I used jQuery to manipulate the HTML that's generated. I can get the footer to add and stay put, BUT when I sort a column, the "totals" row comes back. Tried things like .remove() and .css("display":none"), but, again, when I sort the columns that "totals" row is re-populated. I think it's going to have to be something in the widget-build-table.js file that distinguishes the last row in a .csv file as being the footer, and leaves it alone. What do you think Mottie?

Comment: Maybe try using the `tablesorter-build-complete` event that is triggered after the build adds the table to the DOM. I could also add an option to have the footer target the last row instead of cloning the header row.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I messed around with the build widget... the footer is made from the text of the last row of csv - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/hnzph5us/8/)